# jQuery Radial Menu Malfunctioing in Safari and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, safari

I'm using Nirvana Tikku's Jquery Radial Menu Plugin on [this page](http://staging.www.entercoms.com/index.php?id=2).

The animation works very nicely in IE9, FF, and Chrome. It doesn't work, however, in IE8 or Safari (5). Making matters more challenging, each of these browsers malfunctions in a different way. (Of course, that's not all that surprising.)

In IE8, the curved trapezoids aren't positioning themselves properly by default. Otherwise, the animation works just fine. This leads me to believe the issue has its roots in some quirky, IE8 CSS issue.

Safari, on the other hand, cannot seem to process the Jquery function properly. The menu displays properly initially. However, each click sends the trapezoids scattering.

Only the "keystone" trapezoid displays properly at all times.

I've posted some screenshots here, in case they're helpful: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9534659/screenshots.zip

Any tips would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE (1/25/12)**

I have the animation working on all browsers save the Windows version of FF and IE8. (It works fine in the Mac version of FF.)

Any additional suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it to the class `.radial_div_item` in css this: `-webkit-transition:all .1s ease-in-out;`

Comment: Very helpful, Dave. Thank you. That pretty much fixed the issue in Safari.

Any idea what's malfunctioning in IE8?